# Load custom class data from a file in C++

Tags: c++

I need to create a set of custom class objects from a text file in which the fields are saved one per line. I have the class

```
class Person {
    private:
        string name, surname, address;
        /*...*/
    public:
        void load(istream& in) {
            in >> nome >> cognome >> indirizzo;
    }
}
```

The class as also other fields such as phone numbers but I think this doesn't matter.
And I also redefined the `>>` operator for class `Person`:

```
ifstream& operator >> (ifstream &in, Person& p) {
    p.load(in);
    return in;
}
```

The file would look like

```
Sherlock
Holmes
Baker st.
John
Smith
whatever st.
```

(it MUST be like this, no separators or empty lines, don't ask me why). I then loop through the file like this:

```
Person p;
while (!(in >> p).eof()) {
    add(p);
};
```

The problem with my code is that after adding the last person, the loop is executed again and another Person is created with all fields set to "". I would like the loop to end after the last object is created. How could I achieve this? I'm sorry for my poor knowledge of English and C++.

Comment: You loop should read `while (in >> p) { add(p); }`

Answer (score 0):

Don't test `eof`. Use the unary `!` operator on the stream:

```
while (!in) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is just delete the last person object. Another thing you could try is:

```
do {
     add(p);
} while (!(in >> p).eof());
```

Assuming I understand your question correctly.